# Java Plug-in is not supported by this browser

Tags: java, html, applet

I am trying to run the applet in the .html file. but while running on the firefox browser but it giving error "Java Plug-in is not supported by this browser. More info". My browser is updated and Installed java 8.

How I can Solve Problem

I am using, the following code

```
 <html>
 <title>My Applet</title>
   <head>
      <script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>

  <script>
   var attributes = {codebase:'http://localhost:8080/Puzzle/test',
   code:'S.class',
   archive: 'testww.jar',
   width: '800', 
   height: '600'};
   var parameters = {java_arguments: '-Xmx256m'}; // customize per your needs
   var version = '1.8' ; // JDK version
   deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
 </script> 

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I suspect this because majority of modern browsers stopped supporting Java applet.

Comment: More and more browsers are dropping support for applets - applets are an obsolete technology that you shouldn't use anymore. Specifically, Firefox version 52 and above [do not support applets](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/firefox_java.xml) anymore. Did you try clicking the "More info" link? If you are just learning Java and following some old tutorial about applets, then find a better, newer tutorial. Forget about applets.

Comment: Yes, It takes me to the recommendation of java 8 and java plugin

Comment: If I use the older version of firefox then it works for me?

Comment: For applets I'd recommend Internet Explorer, that still works here. Not Edge of course. As already said all MODERN browsers have stopped supporting applets.